# Correct usage of commas and semicolons

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I am writing an essay to attempt help my friends be themselves and stop worrying about what everyone thinks of them. I am trying to make sure I use punctuation correctly. And I was wondering if I'm using semicolons and commas correctly in the following paragraph. If they are used wrong, please highlight them (if possible) and tell me why and how I'm using them wrong.

---

Be whatever you want to be. Whatever you choose to be is beautiful and flawless regardless of anyone else’s opinion. Be proud of whatever you choose to be. No matter what you choose to be, there will be people that try to bring you down and there will be people that try to bring you up. You should always be proud of being you; be proud of what you look like, be proud of how you act, be proud of how you walk, be proud of how you talk, be proud of how you dress, be proud of your sexuality, just be proud of anything you have. These are all beautiful characteristics you have that set yourself different from everyone else. If you have a big nose, rock that big nose, be proud of your big nose, never be ashamed of your big nose; a big nose isn’t ugly, a big nose is a beautiful trait that you have.  Never put yourself down because you envy a characteristic that another person possesses. You have characteristics they don’t have and they probably envy you for it as well. People might call your characteristics “ugly”, people might call your lifestyle “wrong”, people might  say what you do is “gross”  but regardless of what other people think, you and what you do are beautiful because you are you. What society wants doesn’t matter, you be whatever you want to be. Be eccentric, be dull, be exciting, be extraordinary, be yourself, it’s your life, not society’s life. You make the rules of how to live your life, not society. What society thinks doesn’t matter, you’re just being happy being yourself and living life however you want. Your opinion of yourself shouldn’t be hindered by anyone else, your opinion is your opinion, not society’s opinion, not your family’s opinion, and not your friends’ opinion; it is your opinion.

---

I apologize if this website is not meant for checking like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would change two commas to semicolons.

> Be whatever you want to be. Whatever you choose to be is beautiful and
>   flawless regardless of anyone else’s opinion. Be proud of whatever you
>   choose to be. No matter what you choose to be, there will be people
>   that try to bring you down and there will be people that try to bring
>   you up. You should always be proud of being you; be proud of what you
>   look like, be proud of how you act, be proud of how you walk, be proud
>   of how you talk, be proud of how you dress, be proud of your
>   sexuality, just be proud of anything you have. These are all beautiful
>   characteristics you have that set yourself different from everyone
>   else. If you have a big nose, rock that big nose, be proud of your big
>   nose, never be ashamed of your big nose; a big nose isn’t ugly, a big
>   nose is a beautiful trait that you have. Never put yourself down
>   because you envy a characteristic that another person possesses. You
>   have characteristics they don’t have and they probably envy you for it
>   as well. People might call your characteristics “ugly”, people might
>   call your lifestyle “wrong”, people might say what you do is “gross”
>   but regardless of what other people think, you and what you do are
>   beautiful because you are you. What society wants doesn’t matter, you
>   be whatever you want to be. Be eccentric, be dull, be exciting, be
>   extraordinary, be yourself**;** it’s your life, not society’s life. You
>   make the rules of how to live your life, not society. What society
>   thinks doesn’t matter, you’re just being happy being yourself and
>   living life however you want. Your opinion of yourself shouldn’t be
>   hindered by anyone else**;** your opinion is your opinion, not society’s
>   opinion, not your family’s opinion, and not your friends’ opinion; it
>   is your opinion.

I would change the two because they separate two clauses that don't exist dependently. Good work though!